# Enable Autolayout in iOS 6, Disable Autolayout in < iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, autolayout

If my project supports iOS versions 4.3 and up, how can I enable autolayout in iOS6 **only**, but disable it to the lower versions?

Comment: As an aside, given that non-autolayout hasn't been deprecated (i.e., it's still supported), you could always contemplate just turning off autolayout altogether and calling it a day. Just deliver a non-autolayout app. Or is there some functionality that you plan on enabling via autolayout for iOS 6 users and not present to iOS 5 users? But if you're going through a lot of work to make the app work for iOS 5, I'm not sure why you'd also do an autolayout version, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using storyboards, create two storyboards, one with auto-layout on, and other with auto-layout off. Then one way to check is to load either one based on os version.

i used this little macro

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:(v) options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

this should work too (probably better in some cases then above):

```
if ([NSLayoutConstraint class]) {
    //   >= 6.0
} else {
    //   < 6.0
}
```

and then in my appDelegate:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) 
{
     mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AutoLayoutStoryboard" bundle:nil];
} 
else 
{
     mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NoAutoLayoutStoryboard" bundle:nil];
}

//load initial view controller
UIViewController *rootView = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = rootView;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

ADD: if you are using nibs, and want to enable auto-layout for iOS6 only, you can create a storyboard (or nibs) with auto-layout on, and load them using above version check

Comment: How are you setting 'mainStoryboard'? What's the code to set the storyboard in the App Delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Either you should use two xib files or you should check it programmatically before writing code of auto layouts and constraints.

Comment: how do i check it programmatically? I've been using xib files, btw. :)

Comment: there are multiple ways:From UIDevice class, you can have version string. By checking respondsToSelector, you can check the availability of a particular property.